# Eslint uninstall

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint

I have uninstalled eslint from my system by running two commands i.e

`npm uninstall eslint --save-dev` (to remove it from the package .json)

`npm uninstall eslint`

But after doing all this when I run this command `npm eslint -v`, it shows me the version of the eslint.

How do I completely remove eslint from my system?

Comment: Maybe it is installed globally? Can you try `npm uninstall eslint -g` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to check globally installed packages using the below command:

`npm list -g`

And if you find eslint in the list then try to use this command:

`npm uninstall -g eslint --save`

checkout this link if this didn't work: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+uninstall+eslint

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you installed 'eslint' globally as well

try `npm uninstall -g eslint`

by adding the `-g` you can address the global setup, and uninstall not from the working directory but also from the whole system.
also, consider returning to the project directory you originally installed 'eslint' from and uninstalling it for your project folder.
with just `npm uninstall eslint --save-dev` and `npm uninstall eslint`